# If/else if not executing even though it appears conditions are met inside of a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, if-statement

Pretty much what the title says. I'm to the last bit of this lottery numbers assignment, and I'm not sure why the second set of if/else if statements aren't displaying when I debug. I know that if/else statements are mutually exclusive - but shouldn't an if and then another if both test?
Here's the code.

```
count=0;
while(count<5)
{
    if(lottery[count] == user[count])
    {
        lotto = lottery[count];
        cout<<"So, you matched numbers with "<<lotto <<".\n";
        tally++;
    }
        if(tally==5 && count == 5)
        {
            cout<<"Congratulations, you're the grand prize winner!";
        }
        else if(tally < 5 && count == 5)
        {
            cout<<"A total of "<<tally<<" of your lottery picks matched.";
        }
        else if(tally == 0 && count == 5)
        {
            cout<<"Caution. The following comment is an inside joke. Read at your own risk.";
            cout<<"Bet you feel like a total loser huh? Nothing matched.";
        }

    count++;
}
```

I know I probably ought to have replaced the while loop with a for loop for simplicity's sake but i'm more comfortable with the while.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code line by line in a debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`count` will *never* be `5` when the `if` blocks are executed.

As soon as it becomes `5`, the condition fails and the loop stops.

Answer (score 5):

`count` will never be equal to `5` inside the while loop at the point where your `if-else` conditions require it. If you had incremented `count` *before* the `if-else` then it would have been possible to satisfy one of the conditions (depending on the value of `tally`).

Comment: Darn off-by-one... Just read about that in this chapter too. D'oh. Thanks!

Comment: That's not true. `count` will be equal to 5 after the while loop.